# For Classical Music, is there a database of online recordings that feature the composer (as a conductor or musician)?

Tags: classical-music, recording

Obviously, this question concerns only composers who could have been recorded after [1877, the start of the poor, impractical Acoustic Age of recording equipment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_sound_recording#The_acoustic_era_.281877_to_1925.29); or more realistically, 1925, the Electric Age with improved recording.

I am interested in hearing conductors' participation or playing in their own music (e.g. composers playing their own Piano Concertos as the soloist, or conducting their own orchestral works); but it is too inefficient to Google or search on Youtube for such recordings for each.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the composer that might prove to be difficult. But for instance you can find many instances of Boulez conducting his own material.

There are resources like Naxos music library which gives you a pretty width breadth of various recordings and may make it easier to find a recording involving the composer. There's a little more guarantee you'll find it instead of youtube-ing it and crossing your fingers. It is unfortunately a paid service however.

There's also this [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL951A1398B484F802) and a [forum thread](http://www.organissimo.org/forum/index.php?/topic/72000-composers-who-play-their-own-works/) that also might help.