# Classical music database

Tags: classical-music, database

To evolve my classical music knowledge and appreciation, I think there might be need of an (online) database of compositions, not recordings. I like and use RYM (Rate Your Music), but the format is fit for particular recordings,  not compositions. For budget, space and environmental reasons, I cannot build my physical library, but there are maybe online versions, not (necessarily) with the real music attached, but with notes and marks, like RYM or IMDB for movies or Goodreads for books. So that I could keep track of that fact that I like Bruckner's fourth symphony more than all of Beethoven except the third or remembering my order of the Mozart's piano concertos. This could be a first step towards really differentiate particular good recordings.

Long story short, can I somewhere rate (and share impressions about) classical compositions?

Comment: Related [question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/4676/1733); I don't know of anything remotely similar,but may be I just did not find it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of websites that have records for classical music, but i am not sure if they have it in the way you want but here are the few secure sites with timeless music hostory:

https://blog.feedspot.com/classical_music_blogs/